# Codeblocks ".layout" ".depend" files

Tags: codeblocks, temporary-files

I have a Codeblocks project and I saw that there are `.layout` and `.depend` files that appeared in my project folder. Once I close Codeblocks can I safely delete these files?

Comment: Maybe better not delete them, but add it to the ignore list of your version control system. I makes sense to normally keep them on your local workstation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

'.layout': this is a list of all the open files in the corresponding project, with tab and line position.

'.depend':the dependencies of each file in a project.

Just delete them directly. They are generated while compiling .

Comment: I don't think .layout is generated during compiling.

Answer (score 0):

XiaXuehai is correct when he says "these files " . depend and . layout" are generated... when you delete them and recompile, they are generated again when you close code blocks.